# In-place reverse on a queue works for one and returns None for the other

Tags: python, collections, reverse, deque

I am trying to reverse a queue when I am implementing it through the Python 'collections' module, which when seems to sometimes return None and sometimes return the reverse of the queue as expected.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) suggests that it is supposed to return None but as shown below it appears to be somewhat inconsistent.

The sample code, which I saw in the book I am going through is this:

```
from collections import deque

elems = (2, 6, 12, 20)
dequeObject = deque(elems)

print("Deque object before reversal:")
print(dequeObject)

retVal = dequeObject.reverse()

print("Deque object after reversal:")
print(dequeObject)
```

which in turn returns

> Deque object before reversal:
>
> deque([2, 6, 12, 20])
>
> Deque object after reversal:
>
> deque([20, 12, 6, 2])

When I try to basically do the same thing myself:

```
from collections import deque

my_nums = (1,2,3,4)
my_queue = deque(my_nums)

print(my_queue)

new_queue = my_queue.reverse()
print(new_queue)
```

it returns

> deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
>
> None

Can someone, please, explain why this occurs and what I am doing different from the example? Sidenote, I initially tried to push elements onto the queue like this, which is why I assumed it is refusing to reverse it.

```
from collections import deque

my_queue = deque()

my_queue.append('hello')
my_queue.append(True)
my_queue.append('salamander')
my_queue.append(3)

print(my_queue)

new_queue = my_queue.reverse()

print(new_queue)
```

Comment: In the example, you are printing `dequeObject` (not `retVal`). If you want to do the same thing in yours you need to change the last line to `print(my_queue)`.

Comment: @jprebys oh, yes, right! Thank you! I think my confusion came because the author assigned the `.reverse()` statement to `retVal`, which he actually did not print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.reverse()` performs the reverse in-place does not return anything; use `reversed` to create a new `deque` instead.

```py
new_queue = deque(reversed(my_queue))
```